# Linux: how to detect if a process is thrashing too much?

Tags: linux, process, virtual-memory

Is there a way to detect programmatically?

Also, what would be the linux commands to detect which processes are thrashing?

Comment: Do you mean thrashing the disk? `atop` is a great tool for monitoring disk I/O and memory/cpu usage. http://www.atoptool.nl/

Comment: @LeeNetherton yes thrashing the disk...swapping pages in and out

Comment: `iotop` http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/ too

Comment: How much thrashing is "too much"? I would tend to think that *any* thrashing at all is bad...

Answer (score 15):

I'm assuming that "thrashing" here refers to a situation where the active memory set of all processes is too big to fit into memory.  In such a situation every context switch causes reading and writing to disk, and eventually the server may become so thrashed that hardware reboot is the only option to regain control of the box.

There are global counters swin and swout in /proc/vmstat - if both of them increases during some short time interval the box is probably experiencing thrashing problems.

At the process level it's non-trivial AFAIK.  /proc/$pid/status contains some useful stuff, but not swin and swout.  From 2.6.34 there is a VmSwap entry, total amount of swap used, and the variable #12 in /proc/$pid/state is the number of major page faults.   /proc/$pid/oom_score is also worth looking into.  If VmSwap is increasing and/or the number of major page faults is increasing and/or oom_score is spectacularly high, then the process is likely to cause thrashing.

I wrote up a script thrash-protect - it's available at https://github.com/tobixen/thrash-protect - it attempts to figure out what processes are causing the thrashing and temporary suspends processes.  It has worked out great for me and rescued me from some server reboots eventually.

**Update**: newer versions of the kernel has useful statistics under /proc/pressure.  Also, a computer set up without swap will also start "thrashing" as the memory is getting full, as lack of buffer space tends to cause excessive read operations on the disk.